# reset the selected radio button when recreating the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-radiogroup

my application activity has a radiogroup. It has 2 radio button.

in the xml file, i select the radiobutton1 as default when i start the activity.

Scenario :

- select radio button 2
- Go to phone settings and change the language.
- go back to the application activity.

the activity is created again. But the radiobutton2 is selected.

Actually when i create the activity it should keep radiobutton1 as default selection. But after changing language and coming to my activity it keeps the previous state even though onCreate() is run.

I want to make radiobutton1 selected when i recreate my activity.

Kindly let me know how it can be..where am i doing wrong.

- in my onDestroy() i tried radiogroup.clearcheck()
- i tried to check the id of radiobutton and then set radiobutton1.checked(true).
- i have onClickListener which i use to select the radio buttons.

Somehow the state is not being cleared and i cannot make radiobutton1 as default selection when i create my activity again.

Comment: did you try to set the radiobutton at the onResume method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that onCreate() is called again? Because it's likely that the activity is not destroyed and thus is not created again. If that's the case, you can move the code that selects the default radio button to onResume(), which is called every time the activity is displayed, even if it is not created.

Otherwise, you should post your code so that we can help you.